# YouTube app is not working while using mitm

Tags: mitmproxy

I’m trying to look into network data from iPhone, when I start the mitmweb or mitmproxy the YouTube app and Instagram app stop working. I tried to use tla passtrough script, returned with some errors, tried to ignore hosts (YouTube.com and Instagram.com) same thing. If I use the web version As soon as I input the domain, stop logging. There is any way I can track ignoring the app request? Or there is any way to track a specific https2 site only? Sorry for the long question, I’m not a programmer.

Bottom line I need to track the full url from a specific site.

Comment: Most Google apps use certificate pinning, so they don't accept the installed Mitmproxy root CA certificate. Not sure about how HTTP/2 and QUICK come into play when using Mitmproxy.

Comment: But using —allow-hosts can I ignore the requests from other apps? I tried and it’s not working. I just need to track one https domain. Ignore everything else, sites and apps ( iOS).